# How would you calculate $(200\int_0^\infty e^{-0.8t}-e^{-1.8t}\,dt)/(250\int_0^\infty e^{-0.8t} \,dt)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$\frac{200\int_0^\infty e^{-0.8t}-e^{-1.8t} \, dt}{250\int_0^\infty e^{-0.8t} \, dt}$$

I am confused as to how you would integrate the e's from zero to infinity. What steps would you take?

By the way, the answer is **0.76**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a really trivial integration. Assuming $a > 0$ we have

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-at}\ \text{d}t = -\frac{1}{a}e^{-at}\bigg|_0^{+\infty} = -\frac{1}{a}\left(e^{-a\cdot \infty} - e^{a\cdot 0}\right) = -\frac{1}{a}(0 - 1) = \frac{1}{a}$$

In your case $a = 0.8$ first and then $a = 1.8$

**Complete calculation**

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-0.8t}\ \text{d}t = \frac{1}{0.8} = \frac{10}{8} = \frac{5}{4} = 1.25$$

$$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-1.8t}\ \text{d}t = \frac{1}{1.8} = \frac{10}{18} = \frac{5}{9} = 0.\bar{5}$$

Thence

$$\frac{200\cdot\left(\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-0.8t} - e^{-1.8t}\ \text{d}t\right)}{250\cdot \int_0^{+\infty} e^{-0.8t}\ \text{d}t} = \frac{200\cdot(\frac{25}{36})}{250\cdot (\frac{5}{4})} = \frac{4}{9} =  0.\bar{4}$$

Comment: Wrong answer...

Comment: @CzarGreat Nope. For how you wrote the problem, my solution is correct.

Comment: The textbook says the answer is 7.6. I even put the equation into an online calculator and I still got 7.6. I'm just unsure about what the procedure is to get to that answer.

Comment: @CzarGreat My calculations are correct, check again the whole problem and, in case, rewrite it down in the correct way because those numbers don't lie :)

Answer (score 1):

One typically takes $\int_0^{\infty}f(x)\; dx$ to mean $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_0^R f(x)\; dx$